# Track root domain & Single Page Application in subfolder

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application

I am currently setting up Google Analytics for:

1. http://example.com (public website advertising the product)
2. https://example.com/app (the product, a single page application)

I am using two views to track them. The standard 'All website data' view to encompass the public website and all subfolders (including the single page application) and a separate view for the application itself which contains only application data. In the view for the application I use the filter 'Include only traffic to the subdirectories that begin with /app/' (case insensitive). And within the single page application I log page views like so:

```
ga('set', 'page', 'p=pageName');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

However, I am seeing discrepancies in the 'All website data' view, where there are page loads clearly from within the application recorded as being from the root domain. There are entries for '/p=pageName' and '/app/p=pageName', in other words.

Why is this happening? Do I need to include /app/ in the ga('set') call? Is it related to my filters or that the app is 'https' while the root domain is 'http'? Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that your all pages tag (fired across your website), fires on page load and captures the full URL (document.location): /app/p=pageName. Then, once the SPA loads (history change), the second page view tag fires with the page 'set' capturing the partial url: /p=pageName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles on this question: The answer was to prepend /app/ to the ga() calls, as proposed in my original question.

E.g.

```
ga('set', 'page', '/app/p=pageName');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```